# How we can include node_modules in inside Single-spa Application?

Tags: angular, webpack, node-modules, single-spa, single-spa-angular

Actually we have three angular projects and we integrated concept single-spa (https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/) but we are encountring
issues in running application it's not considering angular.json(node_modules) we are not able call directly also inside single-spa configuration file.

so anyone can help me to confiure to include node_modules in single-spa webpack.

**Here the code for main.single-spa.js**

```
import { enableProdMode, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ɵAnimationEngine as AnimationEngine } from '@angular/animations/browser';

import { singleSpaAngular } from 'single-spa-angular';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { singleSpaPropsSubject } from './single-spa/single-spa-props';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
  bootstrapFunction: singleSpaProps => {
    singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
    return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  },
  template: '<app-vs-root />',
  NgZone,
  AnimationEngine,
});

export const bootstrap = [
  () => Promise.all([
    // loadScript('./node_modules/datatables.net-editor/js/dataTables.editor.js'),
    // loadScript('http://localhost:4800/assets/rappid/js/rappid.min.js'),
    // loadScript('http://localhost:4800/assets/rappid/js/joint.shapes.qad.js'),
    // loadScript('http://localhost:4800/assets/rappid/js/selection.js'),
    // loadScript('http://localhost:4800/assets/rappid/js/factory.js'),
    // loadScript('http://localhost:4800/assets/rappid/js/app.js')
  ]),
  lifecycles.bootstrap,
]
function loadScript(url: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    function onLoad() {
      resolve();
      cleanup();
    }
    function onError(event: Event) {
      reject(event);
      cleanup();
    }
    function cleanup() {
      script.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
      script.removeEventListener('error', onError);
    }
    script.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    script.addEventListener('error', onError);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}



// export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;
```

**Webpack config js file:**

```
const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require('single-spa-angular/lib/webpack').default;

module.exports = (config, options) => {
  const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(config, options); 
  // Feel free to modify this webpack config however you'd like to
  return singleSpaWebpackConfig;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

**angular.json file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Visualizer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Visualizer",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",       
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/material.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/default.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-select-dt/css/select.dataTables.min.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-editor-dt/css/editor.dataTables.min.css",
              "src/assets/rappid/css/rappid.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/lodash/index.js",
              "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js",   
              "./node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",             
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables.min.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/js/responsive.dataTables.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js",              
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-editor/js/dataTables.editor.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/app-new.js"            
          
            ],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true           
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "20mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Sparkster-Visualizer:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Visualizer:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Visualizer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/material.css",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/default.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.css",
              "src/assets/rappid/css/rappid.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/lodash/index.js",
              "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
              "./node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/rappid.min.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/joint.shapes.qad.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/selection.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/factory.js",
              "src/assets/rappid/js/app.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Visualizer:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Visualizer:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Visualizer",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "09642dda-3c7a-46ea-9b06-c0e47c550b1c"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "include node_modules in single-spa webpack?" From reading through the docs of single spa js, it sounds like you build multiple applications and then glue then together with single spa. You shouldn't need to include node_modules. The required dependencies should be included automatically by the webpak build.

Comment: @JohnDengis -   Actually webpack scripts bundling all the scripts into one file but it's not getting initialized correctly so I am getting error to undefine. for example, I'm am using jointjs and backbone library. while running the application both are getting undefined so i could not able to run the application. if you see in above I'm trying through bootstrap using load script actually this is also not working files are getting loaded but before that those libraries (jointjs, backbone) should load. this library I have installed as npm and it's there in node_module. 
how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you try to use webpack-bundle-analyzer to see if those deps are in the bundle? If they aren't in the bundle, that likely means that from the entry point of your webpack build, webpack can't find those imports. The bundle analyzer should also help you debug why it's not finding those deps, as it gives you a nice visual representation of what's being included and why. Apart from that there isn't much I can do to help without a reproduction case.

Comment: @JohnDengis - I have installed webpack-bundle-analyzer. but I am not seeing those libraries(jointjs, backbone). what can I do it now?. Actually I am calling all those libraries inside angular.json. can you please me why it's not taking from angular.json? I have attached my angular.json above. please have a look

Comment: @JohnDengis - This project was working independently but after integrated with single-spa then only it's not working.

Comment: @bagya check this example - this might help you!
https://gitlab.com/TheMcMurder/single-spa-portal-example